# Angular 4 - validator custom function this is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I'm building an app 
with component FormComponent.
inside I'm using reactive forms module from angular core
and create a custom validator.
the function is calling another function by using this - as I supposed it will refer to the FormComponent,
but it refers to be 'undefined'
(?)

The code in onInit defines the FormGroup and FormControl
and outside of it defines the functions

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  formInsurance:FormGroup;
  private id:FormControl;


  constructor(){}


  ngOnInit() {

    this.id = new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(10),
      Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+$|^[0-9]+$'),
      this.foo
    ]);


    this.formInsurance = new FormGroup({
      id:this.id      
    })


  }


  foo(control:FormControl){
  this.boo();
  if(control.value){
    return {
      objToReturn: {
          returned: name
      }
    };
  }
  return null
}

boo(){
  console.log('boo')

}
```

}

Comment: It's written outside onInit, 
but I guess it is called on the onInit scope because this is when the form control validators initial

Comment: yes sorry ,  i have just seen it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The context in the foo method when called from within the FormControl is not referencing the FormComponent.

You can do the following to fix this behavior using **bind** to set the context yourself:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  formInsurance:FormGroup;
  private id:FormControl;


  constructor(){}


  ngOnInit() {

    const id = new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(10),
      Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+$|^[0-9]+$'),
      this.foo.bind(this)
    ]);

    this.id = id;

    this.formInsurance = new FormGroup({
      id
    })
  }


  foo(control:FormControl) {
    this.boo();
    if(control.value){
        return {
          objToReturn: {
              returned: name
          }
        };
      }
    return null
  }

  boo(){
    console.log('boo')

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was annoying to deal with.

Answer (score 12):

And of course, the other alternative is the arrow function, which auto-binds to the `this` context:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  formInsurance:FormGroup;
  private id:FormControl;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(10),
      Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+$|^[0-9]+$'),
      this.foo
    ]);

    this.formInsurance = new FormGroup({
      id:this.id      
    })
  }

  foo = (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors => {
    this.boo();
    if (control.value) {
      return {
        objToReturn: {
          returned: name
        }
      };
    }
    return null
  }

  boo() {
    console.log('boo')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This helped me when `this.foo.bind(this)` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the needed function, take what you want from `this` as a parameter and return the function that you want.
That way it's cleaner because often times you'd only need one value from `this`

in you example, it would look like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  formInsurance: FormGroup;
  private id: FormControl;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.id = new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
      Validators.maxLength(10),
      Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)+$|^[0-9]+$'),
      this.foo(this.boo)
    ]);


    this.formInsurance = new FormGroup({
      id: this.id
    })
  }

  foo(boo) {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
      boo();
      if (control.value) {
        return {
          objToReturn: {
            returned: name
          }
        };
      }
      return null
    }
  }

  boo() {
    console.log('boo')
  }
```