# How to inject a service into a directive in angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-services

I have a directive called UniqueVersionNumberDirective, and I'm using it to validate a reactive form because I need other information besides the value of form control, And I can get this information from the routing params, But I can't get to inject to HttpClient, I also tried to inject another service which can help me out, but that didn't work either, and console throws me this error :

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'http')
```

This is the code of my directive :

````
import { Directive, forwardRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, AbstractControl, FormControl, AsyncValidator } from '@angular/forms';
import { catchError, map, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[asyncValidator][formControlName], [asyncValidator][ngModel]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => UniqueVersionNumberDirective),
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
})
export class UniqueVersionNumberDirective implements AsyncValidator, OnInit {
  @Input() asyncValidator: { coupledControl: AbstractControl };
  createdBy: string;
  projectName: string;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.projectName = this.route.snapshot.data['projectName'];
  }
  validate(control: FormControl): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any }>{
    const {value} = control;
    return this.http.post<{ available: boolean }>(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/version/check/available/${this.projectName}`,
      { value }
    ).pipe(
      map(() => {
        return null;
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        if (err) {
          return of({nonUniqueVersionNumber: true})
        }
        return of({noConnection: true})
      })
    );
  }
  
}
```
````

Comment: This looks all correct. Are you importing `HttpClientModule` in your `@NgModule`?

Comment: Yes, I did import it in app.module.ts

Comment: Looking at the error message, `this` seems to be undefined. It's not about the HttpClient missing or not being injected, is how the async validator is being called by the framework itself. It's weird, it should be working the way it is in your snippet.

Comment: So you mean I can't use a directive as an async validator ?

Comment: They do it just like you in the [angular.io example](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator) (without the forwardRef though).

Comment: @SafwenSoker inject this with `bind`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48785658/3552141

Comment: Exactly, I referred to this page of documentation, and it didn't work !

Comment: Actually on second thought, not sure where one could bind it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using bind as @jhyot mentioned in his comment, but not using HttpClient, I made a workaround using another Service, I created a function in VersionsService to handle the request which is actually a more efficient way, so here's the new code of the directive using another service, which is VersionsService :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class VersionsService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  versionNumberAvailable(
    createdBy: string,
    projectName: string,
    versionNumber: string
  ): Observable<{ available: boolean }> {
    return this.http.post<{ available: boolean }>(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/version/check/available/${createdBy}/${projectName}`,
      { versionNumber }
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the edited code of UniqueVersionNumberDirective :

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, AbstractControl, FormControl, AsyncValidator } from '@angular/forms';
import { catchError, map, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { VersionsService } from '../services/versions.service';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[asyncValidator][formControlName], [asyncValidator][ngModel]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => UniqueVersionNumberDirective),
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
})
export class UniqueVersionNumberDirective implements AsyncValidator, OnInit {
  @Input() asyncValidator: { coupledControl: AbstractControl };
  createdBy: string;
  projectName: string;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private versionsService: VersionsService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createdBy = this.route.snapshot.data['createdBy'];
    this.projectName = this.route.snapshot.data['projectName'];
  }
  validate(control: FormControl): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any }>{
    const {value} = control;
    return this.versionsService.versionNumberAvailable(this.createdBy, this.projectName, value).pipe(
      map(() => {
        return null;
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        if (err) {
          return of({nonUniqueVersionNumber: true})
        }
        return of({noConnection: true})
      })
    );
  }
  
}
```

And here's the code of form validation,
**Please note that I injected VersionsService in this component so that the directive can get when I bind them**

```
constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private uniqueVersionNumber: UniqueVersionNumberDirective,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private versionsService: VersionsService
    ) {
    this.versionForm = this.fb.group({
      number: ['', Validators.required, uniqueVersionNumber.validate.bind(this)],
    });
```

Comment: While this might "technically" (or by accident) work, I highly recommend not doing it like this, for anybody who stumbles across this answer. See also the discussion in the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71619980/3552141

Comment: Yes, In fact this is a temporary solution

Answer (score 0):

After your own answer I think I now understand the full problem. I think you are binding `this` in a bit of a roundabout way, and while it works, behind the scenes it does something else than what it at first looks like. (since the bound `this` is the component and not the directive).

Declaring the Validator as a Directive is only necessary if you are using [template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-template-driven-forms). Then the correct `this` is also automatically bound, without doing anything additionally. See the example in the link.

But you are actually using reactive forms there, which don't bind the directive in the same way as the template-driven. In that case you shouldn't use the `validate` method reference directly, but another one that returns `AsyncValidatorFn`

Add the following to your Directive:

```
validator(): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: FormControl) => this.validate(control);
}
```

And use it in your component:

```
constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private uniqueVersionNumber: UniqueVersionNumberDirective,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
    this.versionForm = this.fb.group({
      number: ['', Validators.required, uniqueVersionNumber.validator()],
    });
```

Comment: I tried your answer, and I get projectName from the params is undefined

Comment: Since we no replies from @jhyot, and his answer didn't work for me, so I'm going to choose mine as the one which solves the problem, until another answer is submitted

Comment: Yeah sorry, since I don't have the full code I probably can't help you more here. If you create a reproducible small Stackblitz or similar, I could take another look at it. There are anyway some further aspects that don't seem correct to me, e.g. injecting a Directive in a component constructor only works if the Directive is on an ancestor element of the component, so I'm not sure how your setup actually fully looks like.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make that and drop the link here, and yes me either, I'm not quite good with directives, but I'm importing the directive in the app module in the declarations section